# Is there a way to limit watchdog logs to only past 7 days in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

The watchdog table for my current site has reached around 180 GB with many redundant/not useful messages. The *Database log messages to keep* option for the site has been set to 1000. We tried using the [Watchdog Prune](https://www.drupal.org/project/watchdog_prune) module but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Please help.

Comment: System cron is the actual system that handles the deletion of old watchdog messages regardless of the limits you set. Have you tried running cron to see if either the core 1000 option or the "Watchdog Prune" contrib module functionality fires?

Answer (score 0):

After normal module installation, configure by visiting admin/config/development/watchdog-prune.

Drupal core's setting of "Database log messages to keep" must be set to "All", and will be set to that by this module. In admin/config/development/logging